# OPP Sign In/Out procedure in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, php5

As a self-taught student of Web-Development and Web Technologies, I created a simple sign in/out form in PHP, just for practice purposes and some fun!

I read the O'reilly's book about PHP and I found one sentence there (I really don't remember where it was though):

> A novice web developer will program procedurally, but an advance one, will know that everything need to be handle as an object.

So it is. I never done an OOP programming before and I though that this will be an excellence motive to do so. In parallel I study about MVC model and I wanted to be sure that I have understand the OOP programming, so it can be used for MVC apps. Is my code clean, well-written to support a big scale app?
What changes do I have to make?

### The Classes

I developed two classes. One called `Main` and it used for procedures that need to be used in the hole app, like connected to DB, get user info and error handling procedures. The other called `UserAuth` holds the Login/Register/Logout methods as well as some other ones.

In the next paragraph I post the code from an *index.php* test page, and the other two files that hold the `Main` and `UserAuth` classes respectively.

### The files

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once 'userAuth.class.php';

    $USER = new userAuth();

    # Check login state
    if( $USER->isLogin()) {
        echo $USER->showEmail();
    }


    # Login
    if (isset($_POST['login-button'])) {
        $login = $USER->Login($_POST['Lemail'], $_POST['LPass']);
        if ($login['State'] == true) {
            echo $USER->showEmail();
        }
        else {
            echo $login['Msg'];
        }
    }

    # Register
    if (isset($_POST['register-button'])) {
        $register = $USER->Register($_POST['Remail'], $_POST['RPass1'], $_POST['RPass2'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        if ($register['State'] == true) {
            echo "We have register your email to our databases.";
        }
        else {
            echo $register['Msg'];
        }
    }

    # Logout
    if (isset($_POST['logout-button'])) {
        $USER->Logout();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Sign In/Out</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="login" method="POST">     
        <input id="Lemail" name="Lemail" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="LPass" name="LPass" placeholder="Password" required="required" type="password" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" id="login-button" name="login-button">Dive</button>
                
    </form>

    <form id="register" method="POST">
        <input id="Remail" name="Remail" placeholder="Your_Email@secretsea.com" required="required" type="text" autocomplete="off" >
        <input id="RPass1" name="RPass1" placeholder="Your Password" required="required" type="password" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="RPass2" name="RPass2" placeholder="Your Password" required="required" type="password" autocomplete="off">     
        <button type="submit" id="register-button" name="register-button">Register</button>
    </form>

    <form id="logout" method="POST">
        <button id="logout-button" name="logout-button">Logout</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**userAuth.class.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'main.class.php';
    require_once '../lib/bcrypt.php';

    class userAuth extends Main
    {

        private $L_UserEmail    =   NULL;
        private $L_UserPass     =   NULL;

        private $R_UserEmail    =   NULL;
        private $R_UserPass1    =   NULL;
        private $R_UserPass2    =   NULL;
        private $ReCaptcha      =   NULL;


        public function showEmail() {
            return $this->getUserEmail();
        }

        public function isLogin() {
            if($this->UserIsLogin()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }


        private function UserIsLogin() {
            if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }


        public function Login($UserEmail, $UserPass) {
            $this->L_UserEmail = $UserEmail;
            $this->L_UserPass = $UserPass;

            if (!$this->exist_LoginEmail()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('User email does not exist in our databases.');
            }

            if (!$this->correct_LoginPass()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('Password is wrong.');
            }

            return $this->doLogin();
            
        }

        public function Logout(/*$emails*/) {
            $this->clearUserEmail();
            session_destroy();
        }

        public function Register($UserEmail, $UserPass1, $UserPass2, $ReCaptcha) {
            $this->R_UserEmail = $UserEmail;
            $this->R_UserPass1 = $UserPass1;
            $this->R_UserPass2 = $UserPass2;
            $this->ReCaptcha = $ReCaptcha;


            /*if (!$this->valid_Captcha()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('Please verify yourself as human.');
            }*/

            if (!$this->valid_RegisterEmail()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('Only letters and nubers are allowed for email. Please see <a href="#">security</a> for more details.');
            }

            if (!$this->valid_RegisterPass()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('Passwords do not match.');
            }

            if ($this->exist_RegisterEmail()) {
                return $this->setReturnState('Email already registered.');
            }

            return $this->doRegister();

        }



        private function exist_LoginEmail() {
            try {
                $STH = $this->DHB->prepare("SELECT UserEmail FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = :user_email");
                $STH->bindParam(':user_email', $this->L_UserEmail);
                $STH->execute();

                # Get the user info
                $row = $STH->fetchAll();

                # Check if username exist
                if (!$row) {
                    return false;
                } 
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private function correct_LoginPass() {
            try {
                $STH = $this->DHB->prepare("SELECT UserPass FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = :user_email");
                $STH->bindParam(':user_email', $this->L_UserEmail);
                $STH->execute();

                # Get the user info
                $row = $STH->fetchAll();

                $isGood = password_verify($this->L_UserPass, $row[0]['UserPass']);

                # Check if password is good
                if ($isGood) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private function valid_Captcha() {
            # FIRST WE CHECK IF THE FORM WAS POSTED BY A HUMAN
            if ($this->ReCaptcha == NULL) {
                return false;
            }

            # HAS THE USER BEEN AUTHORIAZED BY GOOGLE ?
            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Lc6mxcTAAAAAABnITaUtxp3pbH_xUf8fEtj_f7p&response=".$this->ReCaptcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if($response.success == false) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private function valid_RegisterEmail() {
            # CHECK IF EMAIL CONSISTS ONLY a-z A-Z 0-9 characters
            if (!ctype_alnum($this->R_UserEmail)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private function valid_RegisterPass() {
            if ($this->R_UserPass1 == $this->R_UserPass2) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private function exist_RegisterEmail() {
            $this->R_UserEmail .= '@secretsea.com';
            try {
                # STH means "Statement Handle"
                $STH = $this->DHB->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = :user_email");
                $STH->bindParam(':user_email', $this->R_UserEmail);
                $STH->execute();
                
                if($STH->rowCount() <= 0) {  # Check if username is already registered
                    # Email has not registered yet
                    return false;
                }
                
                return true;
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                file_put_contents('../lib/PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private function doRegister() {
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($this->R_UserPass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 13));                

            $STH = $this->DHB->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(UserEmail, UserPass) values(:user_email, :user_pass)");
            $STH->bindParam(':user_email', $this->R_UserEmail);
            $STH->bindParam(':user_pass', $hashedPassword);
            $STH->execute(); 

            if (!$STH) {
                return $this->setReturnState('We could not process your order. Please try again later.');
            }

            return $this->setReturnState(null, true);
        }

        private function doLogin() {
            $this->setUserEmail($this->L_UserEmail);
            return $this->setReturnState(null, true);
        }

        private function setUserEmail($email) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
        }

        private function clearUserEmail() {
            unset($_SESSION['login']); 
        }

    }   # End of User Auth Class
?>
```

**main.class.php**

```
<?php 

    # The symbolic constants of databse connection
    require_once '../lib/config.php';

    class Main
    {
        protected $DHB  =   NULL;

        function __construct()
        {
            try {
                # DHB : Database Handle
                $this->DHB = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_DATABSE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                $this->DHB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                file_put_contents('../PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }

        protected function getUserEmail() {
            return $_SESSION['login'];
        }

        protected function setReturnState($msg, $state = false) {
            return array('State' => $state, 'Msg' => $msg);
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Single Responsibility Principle

I think your code does too much. Try split it into classes, that will focus on doing one thing, for example:

- User class, that will handle all user variables.
- Authentication class, that will handle all Database queries.

Class called Main also does too many things. It will connect to database, return $_SESSION variable and set return state. It has no clue. You can create:

- Session class, that will handle your session variables.
- Database handler class, that will connect and send queries to your database.
- Application class, that will do all the global jobs like set return state.

## PHP Standards Recommendations

PSR is something that will make your work more cleaner and readable. It is composed of basic code standars. There are some links, get familiar with them!

[PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

[Github Accepted Fig-standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted)

## Try to use one MySQL query

Why are you using multiple MySQL queries where you have the same statement??
Look at this login function:

```
public function Login($UserEmail, $UserPass) 
{
    $this->L_UserEmail = $UserEmail;
    $this->L_UserPass = $UserPass;

    try {
        # One statement to rule them all
        $STH = $this->DHB->prepare("SELECT UserEmail FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = :user_email");
        $STH->bindParam(':user_email', $this->L_UserEmail);
        $STH->execute();

        # Get the user info
        $row = $STH->fetchAll();

        # Check if username exist
        if (!$row) {
            return $this->setReturnState('User email does not exist in our databases.');

        # Verify password
        if (!password_verify($this->L_UserPass, $row[0]['UserPass'])) 
            return $this->setReturnState('Password is wrong.');

        # Happy end
        $this->setUserEmail($this->L_UserEmail);
        return $this->setReturnState(null, true);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        return false;    
    }

}
```

It's better, cleaner, more readable and, first of all, much much faster! Think about 10 tousand visitors on your site. It will be 20 tousands queries!

### Also..

- I recommend you to read about SOLID principles. 
  [Grasp SOLID!](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design)
- Read more about the rules of OOP in PHP.
- Good luck!